# Google Sheets - Return all cells based on nearby reference cells/multiple criteria

Tags: indexing, filter, google-sheets, match, google-query-language

I'm attempting to create a table which shows averages based on multiple criteria of nearby cells.

The best way to explain is with my sample sheet (with edit permission):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R3WSa2B0_wzOsp4Z7ktVy_2UVG2tVgo0DK1hehMNW2Q/edit?usp=sharing

The closest I've gotten was to utilize Index Match, though that only returns a value based on a single criteria:

```
=index(C1:C10, match("Joey",C1:C10,0)+2)
```

But of course I need to reference multiple cells/criteria (looking at the "Assigned Person" and the "Job Type"... THEN pulling the value of the cell labeled "Days")

I've also tried a pivot table, HLOOKUP, Filter, and Query, but can't seem to get the multiple criteria AND cell reference in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```
=iferror(average(filter(offset($C$2:$C$10, 2, 0), $C$2:$C$10=$A15, offset($C$2:$C$10, 1, 0)=B$14)), "-")
```

in B15 and fill down and to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at something like this at the moment to pull out row 2,5,8 then 3,6,9 then 4,7, 10 (looks a bit long):

```
=query({filter(C2:C,mod(row(C2:C)-2,3)=0),filter(C2:C,mod(row(C2:C)-2,3)=1),filter(C2:C,mod(row(C2:C)-2,3)=2)},"select Col1,avg(Col3) where Col3 is not NULL group by (Col1) pivot (Col2)")
```

Then this to get the averages without grouping them by Assigned Person

```
=query({filter(C2:C,mod(row(C2:C)-2,3)=0),filter(C2:C,mod(row(C2:C)-2,3)=1),filter(C2:C,mod(row(C2:C)-2,3)=2)},"select avg(Col3) where Col3 is not NULL pivot (Col2)")
```

However you can break this if you change the number of rows in the sheet, because the three arrays in curly brackets could have different numbers of rows.